# PyGears TypeMatchError: [0], Incomplete type: Tuple[Fixp[32], Fixp[32]]

Tags: python, pygears

I have a problem while working on simple module in PyGears. I would like to make simple add operation and after that to do rounding and saturation. Error I'm getting is:

> File "/home/stefan/Test/test.py", line 15, in 
> drv(t=Tuple[Fixp[32], Fixp[32]], seq=[Tuple[3,2]]) \ TypeMatchError: [0], Incomplete type: Tuple[Fixp[32], Fixp[32]]
>
> - when resolving return type "t"
> - when instantiating "drv"

My code is below:

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Fixp, Tuple
from pygears.lib import add, qround, saturate, drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim, cosim

@gear
def adder(data: Tuple[Fixp[32], Fixp[32]]):
  return add(data[0],data[1]) \
    | qround(fract=22) \
    | saturate(t=Fixp[10, 32])
    
########## VERIFICATION ENV ##########
res = []

drv(t=Tuple[Fixp[32], Fixp[32]], seq=[Tuple[3,2]]) \
  | adder() \
  | float \
  | collect(result=res)
  
cosim('test.py','verilator','./home/stefan/Test')
sim()

print(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three problems here:

1. First problem is that you defined Fixp incorrectly. You should also mention how many bits you want for integer part. Therefore you should define it as Fixp[10,32]
2. Output after **add** operation is in Q11.33 format, thus removing 22 bits by round operation doesn't make sense. If you would like to keep all 22 fractional bits then remove **qround** and leave **saturate** as it is. But I would suggest to do rounding to 21 bit and do saturate to **saturate(11,32)**
3. You don't need **cosim**

Having all this in mind working code should looks something like this

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Fixp, Tuple
from pygears.lib import add, qround, saturate, drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim

@gear
def adder(data: Tuple[Fixp[10, 32], Fixp[10, 32]]):
  return add(data[0],data[1]) \
    | qround (fract=21) \
    | saturate(t=Fixp[11, 32])
    
########## VERIFICATION ENV ##########
res = []

sequence = [Tuple[3,2.222356],Tuple[3,3.12]]

drv(t=Tuple[Fixp[10, 32], Fixp[10, 32]], seq=sequence) \
  | adder() \
  | float \
  | collect(result=res)
  
sim()

print(res)
```